# Can someone translate this message?

Tags: translation, meaning

Someone sent me this:

> 所有这些塑料袋都来自于周边非洲国家，因为他们经常应用这种黑色袋子。

And when I translated it sounded offensive.

Comment: Google translate gives a fairly decent translation, albeit not perfect. Not sure what the issue is. https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/en/%E6%89%80%E6%9C%89%E8%BF%99%E4%BA%9B%E5%A1%91%E6%96%99%E8%A2%8B%E9%83%BD%E6%9D%A5%E8%87%AA%E4%BA%8E%E5%91%A8%E8%BE%B9%E9%9D%9E%E6%B4%B2%E5%9B%BD%E5%AE%B6%EF%BC%8C%E5%9B%A0%E4%B8%BA%E4%BB%96%E4%BB%AC%E7%BB%8F%E5%B8%B8%E5%BA%94%E7%94%A8%E8%BF%99%E7%A7%8D%E9%BB%91%E8%89%B2%E8%A2%8B%E5%AD%90%E3%80%82 [All of these plastic bags come from neighboring African countries because they often use this black bag.]

Comment: Offensive? What results did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google Translation](https://translate.google.cn/#zh-CN/en/%E6%89%80%E6%9C%89%E8%BF%99%E4%BA%9B%E5%A1%91%E6%96%99%E8%A2%8B%E9%83%BD%E6%9D%A5%E8%87%AA%E4%BA%8E%E5%91%A8%E8%BE%B9%E9%9D%9E%E6%B4%B2%E5%9B%BD%E5%AE%B6%EF%BC%8C%E5%9B%A0%E4%B8%BA%E4%BB%96%E4%BB%AC%E7%BB%8F%E5%B8%B8%E5%BA%94%20%E7%94%A8%E8%BF%99%E7%A7%8D%E9%BB%91%E8%89%B2%E8%A2%8B%E5%AD%90%E3%80%82) of this sentence is direct and quite accurate:

> 所有这些塑料袋都来自于周边非洲国家，因为他们经常应用这种黑色袋子。
>   All of these plastic bags come from neighboring African countries because they often use this black bag.

It breaks down as follows:

> All [所有](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E6%89%80%E6%9C%89) of these [这些](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E8%BF%99%E4%BA%9B) plastic bags [塑料袋](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%A1%91%E6%96%99%E8%A2%8B) come from [来自于](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%9D%A5%E8%87%AA%E4%BA%8E) neighboring [周边](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%91%A8%E8%BE%B9) African [非洲](http://youdao.com/w/%E9%9D%9E%E6%B4%B2) countries [国家](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%9B%BD%E5%AE%B6) because [因为](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%9B%A0%E4%B8%BA) they [他们](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BB%96%E4%BB%AC) often [经常](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%BB%8F%E5%B8%B8) use [应用](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%BA%94%E7%94%A8) this [kind of] [这种](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%BF%99%E7%A7%8D) black [黑色](http://youdao.com/w/%E9%BB%91%E8%89%B2) bag [袋子](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%A2%8B%E5%AD%90).

As far as I can tell (bearing in mind that I'm just a learner), it's not directly rude.  The "black" only refers to color of the plastic bags, and I don't see any connection with race.

I guess it implies African people in the nearby country (or countries) tend to be litterbugs, and they allow their rubbish to blow into neighboring countries, which might be a bit insulting.

Comment: I agree. I don't feel any insulting. Evil guess is OP is American, he/she can't bear the word "black".

Comment: This is half of the conversation. The topic was about people polluting the ocean. The person showed a picture from China. In the picture, there was alot of trash that was harming sea/land creatures. I don't know if the person was implying that the black bags on the beach were caused by African countries or the meaning was just lost in translation.It seems like I wasn't the only one that got confused.